# Use of eval keyword in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, eval, keyword

What is use of `eval()` during safe cast and smart cast in kotlin?

Is it similar to `eval()` which we use in javascript, python or any other language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [eval()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/eval.html) function is only available in Kotlin/JS , and simply calls the JavaScript [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

This means you can't use it in code you might want to run on Kotlin/JVM or Kotlin/Native.

(Also, while I'm not familiar with Kotlin/JS, I'd imagine that could be quite powerful and also quite dangerous, so maybe caution is indicated…)